# jQuery document change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightbox

In wordpress site I use responsive lightbox plugin. When the image is clicked it opens the popup box with id `fullResImage` . I want to add the function of Pinch Zoomer to it.  Should I bind a function for that or is there any document change function.

The following code does not work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
    $( "img#fullResImage" ).pinchzoomer();
});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$( "img#fullResImage" ).pinchzoomer();` to `jQuery( "img#fullResImage" ).pinchzoomer();`

Wordpress doesnt support the shorthand of "$" and must always be replaced with "jQuery".

Comment: Also I tried jQuery( "img#fullResImage" ).bind( "touchstart", function() {
   jQuery(this).pinchzoomer();
});

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? If so please post them.

Can you copy paste what the rendered HTML looks like with the pop-up box open. It's possible that you aren't using the selector appropriately. 

If fullResImage is the popupbox, you probably need to assign pinchzoomer to the image itself, so something like 

jQuery("#fullResImage img").pinchzoomer();

Comment: It has 2 options (1) HTML <img src="assets/1.jpg" data-elem="pinchzoomer" />  or (2) jQuery $("#img1").pinchzoomer();

Comment: Okay your code looks right, I checked and it seems the plugin does not work with Wordpress natively. See: http://codecanyon.net/item/pinch-zoomer-jquery-plugin/6623080/comments. I recommend contacting the developer as it seems he has a solution available to clients using Wordpress.